# Relation between diferent definitions of Quasicontinuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Defining the class of quasicontinuous functions by 
\begin{equation} QC=(H^{\infty }+C(\dot{{\mathbb R}}))\cap (\overline{H^{\infty }}+C(\dot{{\mathbb R}})).
\end{equation} Where $H^{\infty }$ denotes the closed subalgebra of  $L^{\infty }({\mathbb R})$ consisting of non-tangential limits on $\mathbb{R}$ of bounded analytic functions on the upper half plane.

My question is: How does the above definition of quasicontinuos functions, relate to the next definition of the same class of functions?

Let  $X$  be a topological space. A real-valued function  $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is quasi-continuous at a point  $x \in X $ if for any every  $\epsilon > 0$  and any open neighborhood  $U$  of  $x$  there is a non-empty open set  $G \subset U$  such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon \;\;\;\; \forall y \in G $$

Or how does the second definition follow from the first?

Comment: I think this is just a coincidental collision of terminology: there is no relation. Sarason's class QC [consists of bounded VMO functions](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/VMO-space); this is a measure-theoretic condition, i.e., the functions are defined up to a Lebesgue null set. The second notion has nothing to do with measures; it is purely topological and operates with pointwise values of $f$.